# Conditional Formatting of two cells based on a value's presence in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, countif

In **column B11:B20** users can select a value from a drop down list - the value I am working with is `Other`.

If the user selects `Other` from the list, **Cells 11 in columns N and O** need to highlight.

I can get the formatting working for if the user selects `Other` in the first cell (B11) but can't work out how to get it to work for B12:B20?

Comment: Add more info. We dont know what programming languge do you use for example

Comment: @Krekkon not using programming just using a simple conditional format within excel. Not sure if I can post this type of question on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand your requirement, please select N11:O11 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting,  New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, *Format values where this formula is true:*, enter:

```
=COUNTIF($B11:$B20,"other")>0
```

Format..., choose your formatting, OK, OK.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create conditional formatting based on a formula.

1. Highlight cells N11 and O11
2. Select the condition formatting dropdown item "New Rule"
3. Select the option "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter the formula:

   =($B11="Other")
5. Select the cell formatting you would like
6. Ok and apply everything
7. Copy and paste cells N11 and O11 into the cells below which need to be conditionally formatted.

Comment: Thank you, I can get the format to apply to cells N11 and O11 when "Other" is selected in B11. But if "Other" is selected in B12, cells N11 and O11 don't change?

Comment: I don't think I understand your original question. I assumed when B11 = "Other" then N11 and O11 will get formatted, then when B12 = "Other" N12 and O12 would be conditionally formatted, then when B13 = 'Other"... and so forth through to N20 and O20 be formatted? Why would you want N11 and O11 to change based on B12?

Comment: You are right with what I wanted, It was partially my fault - I have two lots of highlighting that need to be done. There are drop down lists in Column B, there are other options the user can select instead of Other. For Example, if B11 and B12 had Canon, and B13 has 'Other' then cells N13/O13 would be formatted - but I also need cells N10/10 to format (heading). I can get all the formatting to work only for row 11 though, I can't get any formatting to copy through to other cells unless I create a rule for each row

Comment: Can you give me any further information on where it is going wrong? I tested my instructions and it seems to work perfectly except for formatting the headings in N10/O10 as you've only just mentioned that but not provided a criteria. Can you ensure that when you create the conditional formatting you use the formula I put, as this will allow you to copy and paste N11/O11 into the cells below, and the formula will adjust to B12, B13, B14... etc.

Comment: If I selected Other in cell B13 the formatting wasn't picking up in cell N13/O13. The below answer helped to do this - without having to copy anything from cells N11/O11.

Comment: ok, glad you solved the problem, I thought you wanted the N and O column of the row with "Other" written in to be formatted.